# Не срабатывает раскрывающийся текст

Tags: javascript, jquery

Суть такая, у меня 5 таких карточек, я смог добиться чтобы при нажатии открывался текст, это без событий повешанных на мышку, но мне нужно, чтобы при нажатии открывалась одна единственная карточка, поэтому я решил повесить на мышь событие mouseenter и оно добавляет класс show туда куда мне нужно, но! перестала работать вторая функция, которая открывала текст, не понимаю почему, т.к класс show появляется там где нужно.

```js
$('.service-block__card').mouseenter(function() {
  $('.service-block__card-open').addClass('show');
});
$('.service-block__card').mouseleave(function() {
  $('.service-block__card-open').removeClass('show');
});
$('a.show').click(function() {
  $('div#var').fadeIn();
  $('a.show').hide();
  $('.service-block__card').height('800');
  return false;
});
$('a.hide').click(function() {
  $('div#var').hide();
  $('.service-block__card').height('392');
  $('a.show').show();
  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="service-block__card">
  <h1 class="service-block__card-title">Строительство домов</h1>
  <div class="service-block__card-img">
    <img src="img/service/service-1.jpg" alt="service-1">
    <span></span>
  </div>
  <div class="service-block__card-text">
    <p>Какой дом вы хотите иметь? Каменный или деревянный? Вы уже определи ли для себя бюджет будущей застройки?</p>
    <p>Всё строительство условно можно разделить на капитальное и низкобюджетное.</p>
    <p>К низкобюджетному относятся щитовые постройки. Их сложно назвать экологичными и практичными. Мы этого касаться не будем. Наша компания занимается капитальным строительством из бруса, бревна, блоков и кирпича.</p>
    <a href="javascript: displ('var')" class="service-block__card-open">Развернуть</a>
    <div id="var">
      <p>Подробно о ценах в разделе «прайс».</p>
      <p>Если делать сравнительную характеристику стеновых материалов, несомненно, выиграет кирпич. Но в силу дороговизны постройки, уступает своё место блочным материалам: пеноблоку, газобетону и керамзитобетону. Блоки – сравнительно новый материал. Значительно
        дешевле, не требуют широкой кладки, имеют большие размеры и хорошие эксплуатационные характеристики. За последнее время для строительства загородных домов под ключ в Москве и Подмосковье всё чаще применяются именно блоки.</p>
      <p>Дома из дерева – самое экологичное жильё. Наиболее подходящий вариант для жизни и отдыха.</p>
      <p>Интересует строительство загородного дома под ключ в Подмосковье?</p>
      <p>Мы занимаемся индивидуальными застройками с 2004 года.</p>
      <p>Опыт и профессионализм наших сотрудников к вашим услугам!</p>
      <a href="javascript: displ('var')" class="service-block__card-close hide">Свернуть</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Не понятно, вам нужен спойлер как бы? Чтобы открывался только один??

Comment: это не совсем спойлер, там много текста, один выводится сразу, дополнительный при нажатии, на ссылку развернуть

Comment: Вы не рассматривали возможность использовать просто HTML разметку в таком случае? Теги <details> и <summary>, тут скрипт то и не нужен в вашем случае, как мне кажется

Comment: я не знал о существовании этих тегов, сейчас их посмотрел, у summary нет поддержки farefox... а это плохо

Comment: @ Не знаю статью какого года вы читали, но поддержка <details> и <summary> есть во всех браузерах с 2012 года , как минимум, не считая IE конечно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот пример того как это можно сделать:

- открытым может быть только один заголовок,
- чтобы они были закрыты, при загрузке страницы , добавить в `<p>` `style = "display:none";`

```js
  $(document).ready(function(){
   $('.spoiler_links').click(function(){
      if ($(this).next('.spoiler_body').css("display")=="none") {
          $('.spoiler_body').hide('normal');
          $(this).next('.spoiler_body').slideToggle('normal');
      }
      else $('.spoiler_body').hide('normal');
      return false;
   });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 class="spoiler_links">
 ЗАГОЛОВОК
 </h1>
 <p class="spoiler_body">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
 </p>
 <h1 class="spoiler_links">
 ЗАГОЛОВОК
 </h1>
 <p class="spoiler_body">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
 </p>

  <h1 class="spoiler_links">
 ЗАГОЛОВОК
 </h1>
 <p class="spoiler_body">
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
 </p>
```

Для того чтобы можно было открыть все заголовки по одному:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.spoiler_links').click(function(){
  $(this).next('.spoiler_body').toggle('normal');
  return false;
 });
});
```

В вашем примере:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.service-block__card-open').click(function(){
  $(this).next('#var').slideToggle('normal');
  return false;
 });
});
$('.service-block__card-close').click(function(){
$(this).parent('#var').slideToggle('normal');
});
```

```css
a {
background:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="service-block__card">
  <h1 class="service-block__card-title">Строительство домов</h1>
  <div class="service-block__card-img">
    <img src="img/service/service-1.jpg" alt="service-1">
    <span></span>
  </div>
  <div class="service-block__card-text">
    <p>Какой дом вы хотите иметь? Каменный или деревянный? Вы уже определи ли для себя бюджет будущей застройки?</p>
    <p>Всё строительство условно можно разделить на капитальное и низкобюджетное.</p>
    <p>К низкобюджетному относятся щитовые постройки. Их сложно назвать экологичными и практичными. Мы этого касаться не будем. Наша компания занимается капитальным строительством из бруса, бревна, блоков и кирпича.</p>
    <a class="service-block__card-open">Развернуть</a>
    <div id="var" style="display:none;">
      <p>Подробно о ценах в разделе «прайс».</p>
      <p>Если делать сравнительную характеристику стеновых материалов, несомненно, выиграет кирпич. Но в силу дороговизны постройки, уступает своё место блочным материалам: пеноблоку, газобетону и керамзитобетону. Блоки – сравнительно новый материал. Значительно
        дешевле, не требуют широкой кладки, имеют большие размеры и хорошие эксплуатационные характеристики. За последнее время для строительства загородных домов под ключ в Москве и Подмосковье всё чаще применяются именно блоки.</p>
      <p>Дома из дерева – самое экологичное жильё. Наиболее подходящий вариант для жизни и отдыха.</p>
      <p>Интересует строительство загородного дома под ключ в Подмосковье?</p>
      <p>Мы занимаемся индивидуальными застройками с 2004 года.</p>
      <p>Опыт и профессионализм наших сотрудников к вашим услугам!</p>

      <a class="service-block__card-close hide">Свернуть</a>
    </div>
    <div class="service-block__card-text">
    <p>Какой дом вы хотите иметь? Каменный или деревянный? Вы уже определи ли для себя бюджет будущей застройки?</p>
    <p>Всё строительство условно можно разделить на капитальное и низкобюджетное.</p>
    <p>К низкобюджетному относятся щитовые постройки. Их сложно назвать экологичными и практичными. Мы этого касаться не будем. Наша компания занимается капитальным строительством из бруса, бревна, блоков и кирпича.</p>
    <a class="service-block__card-open">Развернуть2</a>
    <div id="var" style="display:none;">
      <p>Подробно о ценах в разделе «прайс».</p>
      <p>Если делать сравнительную характеристику стеновых материалов, несомненно, выиграет кирпич. Но в силу дороговизны постройки, уступает своё место блочным материалам: пеноблоку, газобетону и керамзитобетону. Блоки – сравнительно новый материал. Значительно
        дешевле, не требуют широкой кладки, имеют большие размеры и хорошие эксплуатационные характеристики. За последнее время для строительства загородных домов под ключ в Москве и Подмосковье всё чаще применяются именно блоки.</p>
      <p>Дома из дерева – самое экологичное жильё. Наиболее подходящий вариант для жизни и отдыха.</p>
      <p>Интересует строительство загородного дома под ключ в Подмосковье?</p>
      <p>Мы занимаемся индивидуальными застройками с 2004 года.</p>
      <p>Опыт и профессионализм наших сотрудников к вашим услугам!</p>

      <a class="service-block__card-close hide">Свернуть2</a>
    </div>
    

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: у меня иная структура документа, это для спойлеров

Comment: @AndreyS Это правильный, на мой взгляд, пример. Он подойдет под вашу структуру документа, нужно только заменить классы.

Comment: @AndreyS то что вы описывали в своем вопросе - и есть спойлер, самый обычный

Comment: Проблема этого метода в том, что он также открывает либо все карточки, либо никакую.

Comment: @AndreyS открывается одна карточка,проверьте в последнем

Comment: @AndreyS  вы что то не так делаете

Comment: у меня стоит overflow: hidden, я его убрал, вроде списки начали выдвигаться в низ, спасибо!

Comment: осталась маленькая проблемка, сможешь подсказать?
`
  $('a.show').on('click', function(){
    $(this).hide();
    return false;
  });
  $('a.hide').on('click', function(){
    $('a.show').slideDown("slow");
    $(this).show();
    return false;
  });
`
в первой части этого код с помощью this я смог обратиться именно к a.show который мне необходимо закрыть, а во второй у меня при сворачивании появляются show везде, где не свернуто, и не знаю, как сделать именно для одной карточки

Comment: @AndreyS задавай вопрос отдельно, так ничего не понятно

Comment: @AndreyS или обнови этот

Comment: понял, да наверное пересоздам, если сам сейчас не разберусь

Answer (score 1):

```
   $('.service-block__card').mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).find('.service-block__card-open').addClass('show');
  });
  $('.service-block__card').mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).find('.service-block__card-open').removeClass('show');
  });
  $(document).on('click', 'a.show', function(){
    $('div#var').fadeIn();
    $(this).hide();
    $(this).closest('.service-block__card').height('800');
    return false;
  });
  $(document).on('click', 'a.hide', function(){
    $('div#var').hide();
    $(this).closest('.service-block__card').height('392');
    $(this).show();
    return false;
  });
```

Comment: да, теперь текст развертывается, но проблема вернулась к самому началу, у меня развертываются все 5 карточек, при нажатии на одну,

Comment: я понял в чем дело, нужно как сделать активный класс именно для той карточки, которая выбрана, а у меня в данном случае show добавляется при наведении ко всем карточкам

Comment: хотя нет, пересмотрел код, именно к той на которую наведен добавляется, т.е она и получается активной, странно, почему тогда все скрытые тексты открываются при нажатии...

Comment: @AndreyS Потому что такие селекторы `$('.service-block__card-open')`, `$('.service-block__card')` выбирают все элементы с этими классами на странице, а не только тот, который Вы думаете.

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста, как иначе можно создать активный класс..

Comment: @AndreyS Я уже показал принцип в ответе с использованием `find` и `closest`. Вам нужно еще переделать вот это - `$('div#var')`.

Comment: так ничего и не получилось у меня сделать.